# Disable navigation on iframe outside HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I want to use one iFrame just to show content from another page. I don't have control over that HTML displayed, so I can't change that.
I can somehow 'disable' the navigation over that page?
(I need that page because the data will be changed over there and I need to display the results on my own HTML, but don't want the user to click on it because will change to their homepage with info that doesn't mean nothing to the user)

This is what I have, but the prevent function isn't working on iframe...

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#tabela').click(function( event ) {  
      event.preventDefault();
   });  
});
</script>
<div id=tabela>
<h1>Classificação Atualizada</h1>
<iframe width='700' height='600' frameborder='0' scrolling='no'         src="http://boleirofc.com/classificacao.php?idTemporada=3115"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: No, you can not change the contents of an iframe displaying a document from a different domain client-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overlay the iFrame with a transparent `<div>` of the same dimensions, but higher z-index

```
<div id=tabela style="width:700px; height:600px; position:relative">
<div style="z-index=1000;position:absolute; height:100%; width:100%; opacity:0; top:0;left:0;"></div>
<iframe style="z-index:999" width='700' height='600' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' src="http://boleirofc.com/classificacao.php?idTemporada=3115"></iframe>
</div>
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pp9mE/)